# Absolute convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{n+1}{n^3+2}\left(x+1\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I find the range of $ x $ values for which the following series converges absolutely?

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{n+1}{n^3+2}\left(x+1\right)^n$$

Comment: Try to use Ratio Test. Series inside the interval of convergence must be absolutely convergent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $y=x+1$. The ratio test tells us

$${a_{n+1}\over a_n}={(n+2)(n^3+3n^2+3n+2)\over (n+1)(n^3+1)}\to 1$$

The series $\sum_0^{\infty} a_ny^n$ converges absolutely for $|y|\lt 1$ and so the initial series converges absolutely for $|x+1|\lt 1$ i.e for $-2\lt x\lt 0$ in the real domain.

Comment: $0$ and $2$ are out of the range?

Comment: Sorry I just edited ! The ratio test tells it is convergent for $|x+1|\lt 1$ now we can see that for $x=0$ the series converges absolutely and for $x=-2$ as well.